# Background color in rectangular box is missing for DOC output format

Tags: java, grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using *JasperReports API* to make reports. I had made a *subreport* in which I put a rectangle and fill that rectangle by black color and set as background. When I download this report via *pdf* everything works but when I download this report as *doc* rectangular background color and textField contents are not shown.

Screenshots:

Pdf:[image]

doc:[image]

EDIT:

This is my template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="header" language="groovy" pageWidth="515" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="0" uuid="57cd769e-896d-4b65-9ade-a81ddccb4b4d">
<parameter name="fullName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="phone1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="phone2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="userImagePathInSubReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT
 address.`address1` AS address_address1,
 address.`address2` AS address_address2,
 address.`city` AS address_city,
 address.`country_id` AS address_country_id,
 address.`county` AS address_county,
 address.`house_number` AS address_house_number,
 address.`state` AS address_state,
 address.`street` AS address_street,
 address.`zip` AS address_zip,
 personal_detail.`email` AS personal_detail_email,
 personal_detail.`first_name` AS personal_detail_first_name,
 personal_detail.`last_name` AS personal_detail_last_name,
 personal_detail.`phone1_id` AS personal_detail_phone1_id,
 personal_detail.`phone2_id` AS personal_detail_phone2_id,
 personal_detail.`status` AS personal_detail_status,
 personal_detail.`title` AS personal_detail_title,
 resume.`website` AS resume_website,
 resume.`career_profile` AS resume_career_profile
FROM
 `address` address,
 `personal_detail` personal_detail,
 `resume` resume]]>
</queryString>
<field name="careerProfile" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="website" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="142" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="b844ceda-3ba1-40e0-9fe3-bc353c8f593a" x="0" y="0" width="503" height="137" backcolor="#000000"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="672155ad-36d0-41a2-9495-dd362dc90382" positionType="Float" x="147" y="47" width="121" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{fullName}.toUpperCase()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="7b0d10ef-7253-48fb-aa31-507cf75a1145" positionType="Float" x="378" y="37" width="110" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{phone1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="0ab66ca4-9aa2-416c-b431-27591d5cba4f" positionType="Float" x="268" y="27" width="94" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="b1e9d52c-c272-40fd-bf55-42cb023255da" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="378" y="52" width="110" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <image vAlign="Middle" isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement uuid="1fedbec8-731c-456b-99ef-7477ca2cd933" x="23" y="12" width="99" height="113"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{userImagePathInSubReport}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="8a931b28-74c3-4693-ae2b-530d85469a2a" x="378" y="67" width="110" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{website}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```

Edit: This is the code (in *Grails*) which i am using for generating report in *doc* format . My application uses *JasperReports Plugin 1.6.1*

```
def testSampleForDownloaddoc{
def result = [:]
                result.data = []

                result.data << [data1:"data1",data2:"data2"]



                params._format = "DOCX"
                params._file = "sample"                            //Set your file name this will call to sample.jrxml

                JasperReportDef report = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), result)
                generateReport(report)
}
def generateReport = { reportDef ->
    if (!reportDef.fileFormat.inline && !reportDef.parameters._inline) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;    filename=\"${reportDef.parameters._name ?: reportDef.name}.${reportDef.fileFormat.extension}\"");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "${reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp}");
        response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
        response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
        response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
    } else {
        render(text: reportDef.contentStream, contentType:   reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp, encoding: reportDef.parameters.encoding ? reportDef.parameters.encoding : 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Edit:  This is the *Java* code which I am using:

```
public JasperDesign template(List<SectionOrder> SectionOrderList, List<ExtraSection> extraSectionList, Integer selectedTemplate, String applicationPath, Boolean isUserImageAvailable) throws Exception {
    //Parameters
    JRDesignParameter SUBREPORT_DIR = new JRDesignParameter();
    SUBREPORT_DIR.setName("imagePathInTemplate5");
    SUBREPORT_DIR.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
    expression.setText("\"" + applicationPath + "/images/templateImages/template5\"");
    SUBREPORT_DIR.setDefaultValueExpression(expression);
    jasperDesign.addParameter(SUBREPORT_DIR);

    JRDesignField field;
    field = createField("personalDetail.fullName", java.lang.String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("personalDetail.phone1.number", java.lang.String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("personalDetail.phone2.number", java.lang.String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("personalDetail.email", java.lang.String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("userImagePath", String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("headerImage", String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("phoneImage", String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = createField("messageImage", String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    for (ExtraSection extraSection : extraSectionList) {
        String name = replaceDollarSign(extraSection.getTitle()).replace(" ", "_");
        System.out.println("name-------------" + name);
        field = createField(name, List.class);
        jasperDesign.addField(field);
    }

    JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(20);

    jasperDesign.setTitle(band);

    //Detail
    band = new JRDesignBand();
    int totalNumberOfSubReport = resumeSectionOrderList.size();
    int heightOfOneSubReport = 200 / totalNumberOfSubReport;
    band.setHeight(300);
    band.setSplitType(SplitTypeEnum.IMMEDIATE);
    //Header Data

    JRDesignSubreport headerInfoSubReport;
    if (isUserImageAvailable) {
        headerInfoSubReport = createSubReport(jasperDesign, 0, 0, heightOfOneSubReport, jasperDesign.getColumnWidth(), "resumeList", net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.class, applicationPath + "/report/template5/headerWithUserImage.jasper");
    }

    //User image
    JRDesignSubreportParameter userImagePathParameter = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    userImagePathParameter.setName("userImagePathInSubReport");
    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText("$F{userImagePath}");
    userImagePathParameter.setExpression(expression);
    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(userImagePathParameter);
    //End user image

    //Full name
    JRDesignSubreportParameter fullName = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    fullName.setName("fullName");

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{personalDetail.fullName}");
    fullName.setExpression(expression);

    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(fullName);
    band.addElement(headerInfoSubReport);
    //End of full name

    //Phone1
    JRDesignSubreportParameter phone1 = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    phone1.setName("phone1");

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{personalDetail.phone1.number}");
    phone1.setExpression(expression);

    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(phone1);
    band.addElement(headerInfoSubReport);
    //End of phone1

    //Phone2
    JRDesignSubreportParameter phone2 = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    phone2.setName("phone2");

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{personalDetail.phone2.number}");
    phone2.setExpression(expression);

    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(phone2);
    band.addElement(headerInfoSubReport);
    //End of phone2

    //Email
    JRDesignSubreportParameter email = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    email.setName("email");

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{personalDetail.email}");
    email.setExpression(expression);

    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(email);
    band.addElement(headerInfoSubReport);
    //End of email

    //Address
    JRDesignSubreportParameter address = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();
    address.setName("address");

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{newLineAddress}");
    address.setExpression(expression);

    headerInfoSubReport.addParameter(address);
    band.addElement(headerInfoSubReport);
    //End of address

    Map<String, String> pathMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (ResumeSectionOrder resumeSectionOrder : resumeSectionOrderList) {

        if (resumeSectionOrder.getSectionName().equals("Career Objective")) {
            pathMap.put("Career Objective", applicationPath + "/report/template5 /careerObjective.jasper");
            valueMap.put("Career Objective", "resumeList");
        }
        if (resumeSectionOrder.getSectionName().equals("Personal Profile")) {
            pathMap.put("Personal Profile", applicationPath + "/report/template5 /personalStatement.jasper");
            valueMap.put("Personal Profile", "someList");
        }
    }

    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);

    //Column footer

    band = new JRDesignBand();
    jasperDesign.setColumnFooter(band);

    //Page footer

    band = new JRDesignBand();
    jasperDesign.setPageFooter(band);

    //Summary

    return jasperDesign;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited post,i added my code.

Comment: I am using jasper report API.I have generated the above code using ireport.

Comment: I've reproduced your issue with *iReport*

Comment: Thats great to hear from your side,is this possible that I can get background color in doc format as I get in pdf.

Comment: Is there any way to set color of whole background band.

Comment: I've found solution. It is looks smelly, but it works even in your case

Answer (score 1):

#### I've tried, but nothing:

- *Frame* element, *rectangle* element, *textField* and *staticText* elements with Black *backcolor* as container;
- *image* element with black background as image;
- *Background* band with black background.

The result is: *nothing* works. The backcolor of container is missing.

I get as result the *Table* in *Word* document without background contains texts and image like in your sample.

I think it can a bug of implementation or it can be a "feature" of implementation based on *Apache POI* library.

#### Solution with help of Html component

I've found "ugly" solution, but it works.

You can construct *html* page (any design you want) and use *Html* element to show this page.

The sample of *jrxml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="background_word" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5c50ffd4-6429-4c13-83d1-86221e9aa4bc">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="fullName" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Bill"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="phone1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["234-56-78"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="phone2" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["234-56-77"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="email" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["vk@google.com"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["City"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="userImagePathInSubReport" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["image.jpg"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="careerProfile" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="website" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="241" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="cbd45ce6-f8bf-411c-a453-24a12abe76d8" x="48" y="21" width="327" height="200"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="FillFrame" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<table\n" +
                "style=\"text-align: left; height: 94px; background-color: black; width: 99%;\"\n" +
                "border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\">\n" +
                "<tbody>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"3\"\n" +
                "style=\"vertical-align: top; background-color: black; width: 25%;\"><img\n" +
                "style=\"width: 25px; height: 31px;\" alt=\"\" src=\"" + $P{userImagePathInSubReport} + "><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top; background-color: black;\"><span\n" +
                "style=\"background-color: white;\">" + $P{fullName} + "</span><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><span\n" +
                "style=\"background-color: white;\">" + $P{phone1} + "</span></td>\n" +
                "</tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><span\n" +
                "style=\"background-color: white;\">" + $P{address} + "</span></td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><span\n" +
                "style=\"background-color: white;\">" + $P{email} + "</span></td>\n" +
                "</tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><br>\n" +
                "</td>\n" +
                "<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\"><span\n" +
                "style=\"background-color: white;\">" + $F{website} + "</span></td>\n" +
                "</tr>\n" +
                "</tbody>\n" +
                "</table>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (in *MS Word*):

[image]

*Note*:
I've used *iReport 5.2.0*

---

You can find sample of using *Html* component in `demo\samples\htmlcomponent\` folder of *JasperReports library* distribution package.

---

I saw that you have posted this issue on http://community.jaspersoft.com. Please, let us know if you get the help.

Comment: I have made jar of /demo/samples/htmlcomponent directory and then placed that jar to my application lib and in ireport as well, but when i try to download my pdf it gives  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException  net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponent

Comment: I have resolved  ClassNotFoundException but the above code I have applied and works in pdf but in case of doc still things are not visible.

Comment: Did you try my sample?

Comment: Yep,I have tried your sample jrxml given by you in answer.It works in case pdf but not in doc.

Comment: What version of iReport are you using?

Comment: I am using iReport version:4.7.1

Comment: I am using jasper report 4.5.0.Is iReport 5.2.0 will be compatible with jasper report 4.5.0 which is currently I am using or I should  update my jasper report also.                                        One more thing have you tested the answer given by you on doc?

Comment: You can use templates made by *iReport 4.5.0* in *iReport 5.2.0*. `have you tested the answer given by you on doc?` - Yes, sure. The sample is working

Comment: I have updated my iReport from 4..5.0 to 5.2.0.Your solution works on iReport preview but when i export your solution as doc this is not giving the results.Is this necessary to update my jasperreport-x.x.x.jar .

Comment: It is very strange because I've check this sample. Did you try exactly my sample?

Comment: Yes ,I have used exactly your sample.My application is using jasper plugin which has jasperreports-4.7.0.jar,now i am going to use plugin as inline mode which will use jasperreports-5.2.0.jar,I dont know exactly what is the issue.Your sample is working in case of pdf but I am unable to use it in case of doc.

Comment: Did you try to generate report as *doc* file with help of *iReport 5.2.0*?

Comment: In iReporort 5.2.0 preview is show in doc.But I fail to export report as Doc in My application.

Comment: This is the code(in Grails) which i am using for doc.My application uses jasper plugin 1.6.1

Comment: Is my code gives some useful information to retrieve some conclusion.If you need more information than please let me know.

Comment: I don't know how this plugin works. Are you sure that plugin is using the *JR 5.2.0* library?

Comment: I am sure plugin is using JR 5.2.0,As I am using plugin in inline mode.

Comment: We can try this way :)